# pytest mock my own module imported in tested function

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I want to test a function which import another module.

So i want to mock module.

So my test function :

```
def test_validate_transaction():

    dataset_id = "idx"
    transaction_id = "idy"
    transaction = {
            "transaction_rid" : transaction_id,
            "is_successful" : True
        }
    with mock.patch('table_management.get_last_transaction_id', return_value=transaction) :
        assert validate_transaction(dataset_rid,transaction_rid) == False
```

and my function that i want to test is

```
import json
import os
from table_management import get_last_transaction_id


def validate_transaction(dataset_id,transaction_id):
    try:

        transaction = get_last_transaction_id(dataset_rid)
        return True if transaction['transaction_id'] != transaction_rid or transaction['is_successful']==False else False
    except Exception as e:
        print("An exception occurred " + str(e))
        return {}
```

But by doing this, i receive the error :

```
..\..\..\env\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py:1378: in __enter__
     self.target = self.getter() ..\..\..\env\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py:1548: in <lambda>
     getter = lambda: _importer(target)


 target = 'table_management'

     def _importer(target):
         components = target.split('.')
         import_path = components.pop(0)
      thing = __import__(import_path) 
E       ImportError: No module named table_management

 ..\..\..\env\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py:1231: ImportError
```

do you have any idea what is missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you actually don't have some other issues related to import but you are trying to **mock a wrong object**. You need to mock `get_last_transaction_id` imported in the module where `validate_transaction` is. You didn't mention its name so let's assume it's called `xyz`:

```py
from full_path.to.xyz import validate_transaction

def test_validate_transaction():
    dataset_id = "idx"
    transaction_id = "idy"
    transaction = {
            "transaction_rid" : transaction_id,
            "is_successful" : True
        }

    with mock.patch('xyz.get_last_transaction_id', return_value=transaction):
        assert validate_transaction(dataset_rid,transaction_rid) == False
```